# Chart.js - Line chart does not render all points when using Point[] format

Tags: chart.js

Charts.js does not render all data points when using `Point[]` format.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/tmrczk/pen/JgvYoR)

Questions:

1. Why only two out of four data points are rendered for each dataset?
2. Why there are no ticks on X axis?
3. Why is "undefined" string shown on point hover?
4. How can I get both X and Y values display on point hover?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding "scales" option fixed the problem:

```js
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
      }]
    }
```